# Changing this graphic to a top down perspective

Tags: adobe-illustrator, perspective, illustrator-effects

I've tried to use the perspective grid to get the same effect as the monitor on my wordpress logo graphic but nothing is working. How would i go about applying the same perspective to my wordpress graphic as the monitor in the picture.

[image: screenie]

Comment: Can you post your image on the site itself - if the image is ever deleted, or, like me, you can't access the site due to company policy, then we haven't got a clue what you're really talking about.

Comment: Have you tried drawing a square around your shape, then modifying both by dragging the corners to the square in the screen? That's how I would do it.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use<kbd>Effect > Distort & Transform > Free Distort...</kbd>. There, you can drag the corners of your object to warp it into the right shape.

You could also use an `Envelope Distort`:

- copy the shape you want the icon to fit in;
- resize the icon so it fits into the shape;
- position the shape over the resized icon;
- select both objects;
- <kbd>Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Top Object</kbd>.